# Something about regular expression

Tags: regex

I am new in regular expression and seems I get lost into it.

```
var data = [
{"label":"1","id":"31507","url":"/restaurant/sr2.htm?&shopid=31507","name":"content1","lat":"22.2874683487767","long":"114.14677977562","zoom":"18","photo":"//static3.openrice.com.hk/UserPhoto/photo/0/OA/004SR09CA05ACD14878033s.jpg","district":"上環","addr":"content2","phone":"content3"
```

If I want to get the content1, content2 and content3 in above script, what regular expression I should use to get it?

I have tried "/.*","name":"(.*)"/msU" to get content1, but failed.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like json string - better use some json parser available on your platform to get all data it contains, I don't think it a right task for regexes...

Comment: if you use Jquery ...`jQuery.parseJSON(data );`

Comment: content1 - content3 appear to be values, not keys.  What value do you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

use`.toJSONString();` and parse watever u want
 [see here](http://socket7.net/article/how-to-safely-parse-json)